# Match the input with string using lex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I'm trying to match the prefix of the string **Something**. For example, If input **So,SOM,SomeTH,some,S**, it is all accepted because they are all prefixes of **Something**.

My code

```
Ss[oO]|Ss[omOMOmoM] {
        printf("Accept Something": %s\n", yytext);
}
```

Input

```
Som
```

Output

```
Accept Something: So
Invalid Character
```

It's suppose to read **Som** because it is a prefix of **Something**. I don't get why my code doesn't work. Can anyone correct me on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you think the meaning of

```
Ss[oO]|Ss[omOMOmoM]
```

is, but what it matches is either:

- an `S` followed by an `s` followed by exactly one of the letters `o` or `O`, or
- an `S` followed by an `s` followed by exactly one of the letters `o`, `O`, `m` or `M`. Putting a symbol more than once inside a bracket expression has no effect.

Also, I don't see how that could produce the output you report. Perhaps there was a copy-and-paste error, or perhsps you have other pattern rules.

If you want to match prefixes, use nested optional matches:

```
s(o(m(e(t(h(i(ng?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

If you want case-insensitive matcges, you could write out all the character classes, but that gets tiriesome; simpler is to use a case-insensitve flag:

```
(?i:s(o(m(e(t(h(i(ng?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)
```

`(?i:` turns on the `i`nsensitive flag, until the matching close parenthesis.

In practice, this is probably *not* what you want. Normally, you will want to recognise a complete word as a token. You could then check to see if the word is a prefix in the rule action:

```
[[:alpha:]]+    { if (yyleng <= strlen("something") && 0 == strncasemp(yytext, "something", yyleng) { 
                  /* do something */
                  } 
                }
```

There is lots of information in the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).

Answer (score 2):

Right now your code (as shown) should only match "Sso" or "SsO" or "Ssm" or "SsM".

You have two alternatives that each start with `Ss` (without square brackets) so those will be matched literally. That's followed by either `[oO]` or `[omOMomoM]`, but the characters in square brackets represent alternatives, so that's equivalent to `[oOmM]` --i.e., any one character of of `o`, `O`, `m` or `M`.

I'd start with: `%option caseless` to make it a case-insensitive scanner, so you don't have to list the upper- and lower-case equivalents of every letter.

Then it's probably easiest to just list the alternatives literally:

```
s|so|som|some|somet|someth|somethi|somethin|something { printf("found prefix"); }
```

I guess you can make the pattern a bit shorter (at least in the source code) by doing something on this order:

```
s(o(m(e(t(h(i(n(n(g)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)? { printf("found prefix"); }
```

Doesn't seem like a huge improvement to me, but some might find it more attractive than I do.

If you don't want to use `%option caseless` the basic idea helps more:

```
[sS]([oO]([mM]([eE]([tT]([hH]([iI]([nN]([gG])?)?)?)?)?)?)?)? { printf("found prefix"); }
```

Listing every possible combination of upper and lower case would get tedious.